# How to group some fild and show in rows with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, categories

I have these fields in MySQL:

```
rpt_id, rpt_entrydate, rpt_exitdate, rpt_date
```

and the values of these fields are as follows:

```
1, 2012-11-02, 2012-11-03, 2011-11-26
2, 2011-11-23, 2012-11-16, 2011-11-26
3, 2011-11-25, 2012-11-26, 2011-11-26
4, 2011-10-14, 2012-10-17, 2011-10-13
5, 2011-10-05, 2012-10-09, 2011-10-13
6, 2011-10-15, 2012-10-18, 2011-10-13
```

I want my result to look like this but it doesn't work:

```
2011-11-25, 2012-11-26, 2011-11-23, 2012-11-16, 2012-11-02, 2012-11-03, 2011-11-26
2011-10-15, 2012-10-18, 2011-10-05, 2012-10-09, 2011-10-14, 2012-10-17, 2011-10-13
```

Comment: i dont understand anything how u want your results to be?

Comment: [What have you tried??](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: As well as some code, can you explain what the results represent. They seem awfully random.

Comment: this is my DB. the value of field "rpt_entrydate" and "rpt_exitdate" are timestame http://up.download.ir/di-Y9CP.jpg

Comment: this is my code: http://up.download.ir/di-CFNR.jpg

Comment: Post the code.  Not a screencap of the code.  The code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are attempting to string together all the dates associated with each `rpt_date` by group. You can do this with a `GROUP_CONCAT()` and a couple of [`CONCAT_WS()` concatenations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).

The inner `CONCAT_WS()` combines the pair of `rpt_entrydate, rpt_exitdate` into a comma-separated string, and the outer `CONCAT_WS()` pairs the `GROUP_CONCAT()` string with its `rpt_date` group.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT_WS(', ',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT_WS(', ', rpt_entrydate, rpt_exitdate)
    ),  rpt_date
  ) AS datestring
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY rpt_date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a07a/5

Comment: Yes, it's working. I'm so very thank you. :)